# Android studio import fails

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Im trying to import the sample SDK APIDemos app (I also tried to import another project I have in eclipse) and in both cases it says "Grade refresh build failed... peer not authenticated".
I check on the eclipse project gradle propeties file that it is `http` and not `https` and still same problem.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** now I am getting the same problem when trying to create a new project, please help!

Comment: what version of android studio.  I just started using the .8+ version?

Comment: Newest version, 0.8.14